# Ansible merge different size list which has key value pairs

Tags: list, merge, ansible

I have two list:

```
list1:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
```

```
list2:
  - file: f4
    t_perm: '755'
  - file: f3
    perm: '677'
```

I have to merge them into new list as below:

```
list3:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
    t_perm: '755'
```

I tried as below, but it did not merge correctly.

```
  - name: merge the list 
    set_fact:
     list3: "{{ list3 + [ item[0] | combine(item[1]) ]  }}"
    when: item[0].file == item[1].file
    loop: "{{ list1(sort(attribute='file')| zip(list2|sort(attribute='file') | list}}"
```

Additinally, if possible can list3 can have an  extra field that the target file is missing?

```
list3:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
    stat: not_found
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
    stat: not_found
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
    t_perm: '755'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update.

The filter *community.general.lists_mergeby* does the job. Given the lists

```yaml
  list1:
    - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
    - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
    - {file: f3, perm: '755'}
    - {file: f4, perm: '700'}

  list2:
    - {file: f4, t_perm: '755'}
    - {file: f3, t_perm: '677'}
```

Declare *list3*

```yaml
  list3: "{{ [list1, list2]|community.general.lists_mergeby('file') }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  list3:
    - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
    - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
    - {file: f3, perm: '755', t_perm: '677'}
    - {file: f4, perm: '700', t_perm: '755'}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    list1:
      - {file: f1, perm: '777'}
      - {file: f2, perm: '677'}
      - {file: f3, perm: '755'}
      - {file: f4, perm: '700'}
    list2:
      - {file: f4, t_perm: '755'}
      - {file: f3, t_perm: '677'}

    list3: "{{ [list1, list2]|community.general.lists_mergeby('file') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: list3|to_yaml
```

---

Original.

The tasks

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ (list1 + list2)|
                   groupby('file')|
                   map('last')|
                   map('combine')|
                   list }}"
    - debug:
        var: list3
```

give

```yaml
  list3:
  - file: f1
    perm: '777'
  - file: f2
    perm: '677'
  - file: f3
    perm: '755'
    t_perm: '677'
  - file: f4
    perm: '700'
    t_perm: '755'
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine. can you please give some explanation, mainly what the map('last') does?

Comment: The filter `last` extracts the last item from a list. The opposite is `first`. The filter `groupby` creates a list where each item is another list with 2 items. The filter `map` then applies the filter `last` on each item. **It's very easy to learn all details on your own. Simply remove the filters step by step from the end of the chain and display the results. Always keep the last filter `list`.**

Comment: I have one more condition. If it is present in list1 and not in list2, then i need to merge. But if it is present in list2 and not in list1, then I need not merge it, that needs to be ignored. could you please advise.

Comment: @Ash open new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest path forward is first converting `list1` into a dictionary, then merging in the elements of `list2`, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    list1:
      - file: f1
        perm: '777'
      - file: f2
        perm: '677'
      - file: f3
        perm: '755'
      - file: f4
        perm: '700'
    list2:
      - file: f4
        t_perm: '755'
      - file: f3
        perm: '677'

  tasks:
    - name: convert list1 into a dictionary
      set_fact:
        d1: "{{ d1|combine({item.file: item}) }}"
      loop: "{{ list1 }}"
      vars:
        d1: {}

    - name: update d1 with the values from list2
      set_fact:
        d1: "{{ d1|combine({item.file: item}, recursive=true) }}"
      loop: "{{ list2 }}"
    
    - name: set list3 to the values of d1
      set_fact:
        list3: "{{ d1.values()|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: list3
```

The output of the above is:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list3": [
        {
            "file": "f1",
            "perm": "777"
        },
        {
            "file": "f2",
            "perm": "677"
        },
        {
            "file": "f3",
            "perm": "677"
        },
        {
            "file": "f4",
            "perm": "700",
            "t_perm": "755"
        }
    ]
}
```

...which is I think what you were looking for.